# Dealing with painfully long namespace names in headers

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files, c++14

Is there anything that can be done about looong symbols that need to be referenced in header files, e.g. `ABDEFGHIJ::ZXCBVB::AWEDADSDEM::GFGBKGDF::Tools::Item`? I know in header files you aren't supposed to using `using` because it messes up anybody who includes it.

The only working feature that cleans up after itself that I can even think of would be `#define`+`#undef` but that seems terrible.

Is there a new feature that solves this that I'm not aware of? I'm also interested in any popular proposals. Maybe `using` with a bracketed block syntax, to let me restrict the effect to just my header...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not good practice to have a `using namespace` using directive at global scope in a header file. There are a number of less drastic things you can do that are fairly benign however.

- Inside an inline or template function in a header, you can use a using directive without affecting anyone else. This saves you having to qualify all the names in a non-trivial function body.
- As Maksim Solovjov suggests, you can use namespace aliases to cut down on typing, with the caveat that a namespace alias at global scope will introduce that alias to anyone including your header so that may not be desirable.
- C++11 introduced [type aliases and alias templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) which can be used in a header at class scope, function scope or namespace scope (you may still want to avoid using them at global scope) to give a shorter name to types. This is particularly useful when dealing with template types with long names like e.g. `std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::function<float(float)>>>`
- C++11 and 14 type deduction through the `auto` keyword can greatly reduce the need to name long types in headers, whether function return types, local variables or parameters to lambdas.
- C++11 `decltype` can also be useful to avoid saying the names of long types in certain situations.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I feel.

First of all you should create your *own* namespaces. Then you can draw in other namespace symbols without polluting the global namespace.

If the namespace you are accessing is truly *massive* (like `std`) then I would *always* either use the `std::` qualifier or declare the types explicitly:

```
namespace my_project {

std::string s; // qualify

// or declare specific types
using std::string;

} // my_project
```

If the namespace is from your own project or a *relatively small* library then I see no reason not to inject the whole namespace into your own (never into the global namespace).

```
namespace my_project {

using namespace xmltools; // never do this in global namespace

// use without prefix here

} // my_project
```

The key is to use your *own* namespaces. Then what you do inside them will have less affect on people using your headers.

I think the main point is to remember that if someone injects the symbols from *your* namespace into their own they should not be *surprised* by what it contains.

So if my library builds on another library it may be *normal* for my library to contain the type symbols from the other library and someone injecting my namespace into theirs would also expect that.

Comment: "Here is what I feel." doesn't seem like a strong preamble.

Comment: @AaronHall Well I suspect people are going to have different opinions on this subject and I am very open to other people's input. My practices may be considered a little loose for some people.

Comment: @AaronHall: I agree with Galik being overly cautious with his answer.  I do this all the time in my **.cpp** files, but rarely will do it in **.h** files simply because my namespaces tend to contain classes that may reference other classes in the same namespace.  Even within a single namespace, I don't want to introduce the possibility of an alias simply by which header(s) I include.  As a counterpoint to Galik, my practices may be considered a little too _pedantic_ for some people.  In general, I would rather be explicit simply because code is read more than it's written.

Answer (score 2):

You can have [namespace aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias):

```
namespace fbz = foo::bar::baz;
```

However, you would introduce `fbz` to every file that includes your header.

Comment: That exists since C++98.

Comment: Looks like these definitions are themselves scopeable to within a namespace, fortunately, which limits pollution to at least being just our namespace. I may use this in a few cases